# How do I submit a form with a particular field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, mechanize

Need to select and submit a form on a page containing many different forms, which has a hidden field with a particular value.

I know there's [`form.fields_with()`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-click_button) to select form fields, and [`page.form_with()`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-click_button), to select forms with particular attributes, but I want to select a form which has a hidden field with the value attribute 'xxxxx', for example.

Is there a way of doing this in Mechanize? Or am I stuck using xpath or a hack solution? The XPath for what I want is

```
xpath("//form[div/input/@value='xxx']").click_button
```

Of course I cannot `click_button` on an xpath, though.

Comment: You can do form_with and add a criteria like name, action and such of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
page.form_with :form_node => page.at(xpath)
```